# Star Wars game from 2010ish to do McDonalds

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

I seem to remember an old Star Wars game from maybe 10 years ago. I know it was based off of the Cartoon Network series from back then. I also seem to remember it having something to do with McDonalds.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Are you talking about a [Star Wars *video* game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_video_games)?

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't specify if what you're looking for is a video game, a toy or maybe a tabletop I'll just list here what I think you meant.

---

### Idea #1 - McDonalds 2010-2011 STAR WARS - The Clone Wars set

This is a set of Happy Meal toys McDonalds released in 2010 and 2011 tied into The Clone Wars cartoon.

---

### Idea #2 - [Lego Star Wars III: The Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Star_Wars_III:_The_Clone_Wars)

This is a video game about the clone wars released in 2011 and is part of the Lego Star Wars series of video games.

This doesn't seem to tie into McDonalds at all but it seems there are no video games released or endorsed by McDonalds about the Star Wars universe.

Comment: You have answers here so keeping them in answers is fine. However, it would be best to [edit] out the "noise" of the posts i.e. why you answered and didn't comment. It would also be better, to try and add in more details about why these are "correct". Lastly, I usually say to post a new answer for each possible answer (idea) but in this case they seem to lead on from each other so should be fine.